# Append Cost very high on Partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I have a query joining two tables partitioned on timestamp column. Both tables are filtered on current date partition. But query is unusually slow with APPEND Cost of the driving table very high.

Query and Plan : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/wVA

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..174042.82 rows=16 width=494) (actual time=0.482..20.133 rows=1713 loops=1)
  Output: tran.transaction_status, mgwor.apx_transaction_id, org.organisation_name, mgwor.order_status, mgwor.request_date, mgwor.response_date, (date_part('epoch'::text, mgwor.response_date) - date_part('epoch'::text, mgwor.request_date))
  Buffers: shared hit=5787 dirtied=3
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..166837.32 rows=16 width=337) (actual time=0.459..7.803 rows=1713 loops=1)
        Output: mgwor.apx_transaction_id, mgwor.order_status, mgwor.request_date, mgwor.response_date, org.organisation_name
        Join Filter: ((account.account_id)::text = (mgwor.account_id)::text)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3007
        Buffers: shared hit=589
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.27..40.66 rows=4 width=54) (actual time=0.203..0.483 rows=2 loops=1)
              Output: account.account_id, org.organisation_name
              Join Filter: ((account.organisation_id)::text = (org.organisation_id)::text)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 289
              Buffers: shared hit=27
              ->  Index Scan using account_pkey on mdm.account  (cost=0.27..32.55 rows=285 width=65) (actual time=0.013..0.122 rows=291 loops=1)
                    Output: account.account_id, account.account_created_at, account.account_name, account.account_status, account.account_valid_until, account.currency_id, account.organisation_id, account.organisation_psp_id, account."account_threeDS_required", account.account_use_webhook, account.account_webhook_url, account.account_webhook_max_attempt, account.reporting_account_id, account.card_type, account.country_id, account.product_id
                    Buffers: shared hit=24
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.84 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=291)
                    Output: org.organisation_name, org.organisation_id
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
                    ->  Seq Scan on mdm.organisation_smd org  (cost=0.00..3.84 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.017..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Output: org.organisation_name, org.organisation_id
                          Filter: ((org.organisation_name)::text = 'ABC'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 67
                          Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..166576.15 rows=3835 width=473) (actual time=0.127..2.826 rows=2360 loops=2)
              Output: mgwor.apx_transaction_id, mgwor.order_status, mgwor.request_date, mgwor.response_date, mgwor.account_id
              Buffers: shared hit=562
              ->  Append  (cost=0.15..166556.97 rows=3835 width=473) (actual time=0.252..3.661 rows=2360 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=562
                    Subplans Removed: 1460
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.mgworderrequest_part_20200612 mgwor  (cost=50.98..672.23 rows=2375 width=91) (actual time=0.251..2.726 rows=2360 loops=1)
                          Output: mgwor.apx_transaction_id, mgwor.order_status, mgwor.request_date, mgwor.response_date, mgwor.account_id
                          Recheck Cond: ((mgwor.request_type)::text = ANY ('{CARD,CARD_PAYMENT}'::text[]))
                          Filter: ((mgwor.request_date >= date(now())) AND (mgwor.request_date < (date(now()) + 1)))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=549
                          Buffers: shared hit=562
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mgworderrequest_part_20200612_request_type_idx  (cost=0.00..50.38 rows=2375 width=0) (actual time=0.191..0.192 rows=2361 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((mgwor.request_type)::text = ANY ('{CARD,CARD_PAYMENT}'::text[]))
                                Buffers: shared hit=13
  ->  Append  (cost=0.14..435.73 rows=1461 width=316) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1713)
        Buffers: shared hit=5198 dirtied=3
        Subplans Removed: 1460
        ->  Index Scan using transaction_part_20200612_pkey on public.transaction_part_20200612 tran  (cost=0.29..0.87 rows=1 width=42) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1713)
              Output: tran.transaction_status, tran.transaction_id
              Index Cond: (((tran.transaction_id)::text = (mgwor.apx_transaction_id)::text) AND (tran.transaction_created_at >= date(now())) AND (tran.transaction_created_at < (date(now()) + 1)))
              Filter: (tran.transaction_status IS NOT NULL)
              Buffers: shared hit=5198 dirtied=3
Planning Time: 19535.308 ms
Execution Time: 21.006 ms
```

Partition pruning is working on both the tables.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks,
VA

Comment: That execution plan is unreadable. Can you post the raw output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`?

Comment: Explain plan pasted

Comment: It's the planning time which is very high compared,to the execution time: that's very unusual.

Comment: Planning time=19 seconds vs execution time=21 milliseconds !

Comment: How many partitions are there?

Comment: Around 1460 partitions for each table.

Comment: This looks like a bug: what is your exact PostgreSQL version - output of `select version();`.

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: I have found only planner bug for partitions fixed in 11.7 (*Allow the planner to apply potentially-leaky tests to child-table statistics, if the user can read the corresponding column of the table that's actually named in the query*). I recommend you submit your case to https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-bugs/.

Comment: Does this happen every time you run that query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the cost estimate for the append is so large, but presumably you are really worried about how long this takes, not how large the estimate is.  As noted, the actual time is going to planning, not to execution.

A likely explanation is that it was waiting on a lock.  Time spent waiting on a table lock for a partition table (but not for the parent table) gets attributed to planning time.